# FloatingActionButton is coppied in every row of ListView

Tags: java, android, android-listview, floating-action-button

What I am trying to do is have just one FAB in fragment but I am getting FAB in every line of the ListView. Also I am using Custom ListAdapter.

This fragment is using layout with ListView.

```java
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
    import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ListView;

    import com.google.gson.Gson;

    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;


    /**
     * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
     */
    public class Todos extends Fragment {


        private ListView myListView;

        public Todos() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }

        FloatingActionButton.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.navigation);
                navigation.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_new_task);
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_layout, new NewTask()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            }

        };

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_todos, container, false);
            myListView = view.findViewById(R.id.listTodos);
            myListView.setClickable(true);
            final FloatingActionButton button = view.findViewById(R.id.addTaskButton);
            button.setOnClickListener(listener);

            printAllTasks();

            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            return view;
        }

        private void printAllTasks() {
            final Gson gson = new Gson();

            final Task[] tasksArray = gson.fromJson(fetchAllData(), Task[].class);
            if (tasksArray != null) {
                final List<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(tasksArray));
                TaskListAdapter adapter = new TaskListAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.fragment_todos, tasks);
                myListView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }

        private String fetchAllData() {
            String text = "";
            try {
                final FileInputStream fin = getActivity().getApplicationContext().openFileInput("TaskJson");
                int tmp;
                while ((tmp = fin.read()) != -1) {
                    text = text + Character.toString((char) tmp);
                }
                fin.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return text;
        }
    }
```

My Custom Adapter:

```java
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import java.util.List;

    class TaskListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Task> {

        private Context mContext;
        private int mResource;


        public TaskListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Task> objects) {
            super(context, resource, objects);
            this.mContext = context;
            this.mResource = resource;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View v = convertView;

            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi;
                vi = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
                v = vi.inflate(mResource, null);
            }

            final int id = getItem(position).getId();
            final String name = getItem(position).getName();
            final String description = getItem(position).getDescription();
            final int xp = getItem(position).getXp();
            final String color = getItem(position).getColor();

            TextView tvName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textName);
            TextView tvDescription = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textDescription);
            TextView tvXP = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textXps);

            tvName.setText(name);
            tvDescription.setText(description);
            tvXP.setText(Integer.toString(xp));

            return v;
        }
    }
```

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listTodos"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textDescription"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textXps"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/addTaskButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24dp"
            app:backgroundTint="#ff0000"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.Co

nstraintLayout>
```

What I want:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This piece of code (the FAB widget)

```
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/addTaskButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24dp"
        app:backgroundTint="#ff0000"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
```

should be in the fragment's view (`fragment_todos`) instead of the list item's view.

In conjunction, your ListView's list item should be a separate layout file and not the same layout file as the fragment's, which is what you seem to be doing here:

```
    TaskListAdapter adapter = new TaskListAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.fragment_todos, tasks);
    myListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

---

Try checking out this tutorial: https://www.journaldev.com/10416/android-listview-with-custom-adapter-example-tutorial

On another note, I would highly recommend learning how to use a RecyclerView.

Answer (score 0):

the code looks ok to me, it may be possible that it's a rendering bug of ListView (that is deprecated), I would suggest you to try to use RecyclerView instead, it's pretty similar to ListView and probably you just have to modify your adapter to work on RecyclerView, but it's worth it since they're more versatile.

Here's a link to a guide that may be helpful https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview